# How to get a field from external API using Google Scripts UrlFetchApp.fetch?

Tags: google-apps-script, urlfetch

How do I get the field: `dataMain` in external API using Google Apps Script `UrlFetchApp.fetch`?

Two days on this with no results. The assistance from customer support for this API is a link to https://pestroutes.api-docs.io/3.1/welcome/how-to-use-the-pestroutes-api which does not seem to help. This seems like it should be a very simple thing to do, but apparently not.

External API Docs: https://pestroutes.api-docs.io/3.1/import/importmainobject

Sample Code (Google Apps Script):

```
function runTest() {
   var at = 'authenticationToken=<myToken>'
   var ak = 'authenticationKey=<myKey>'
   var url ='https://<myCompanyDomain>.pestroutes.com/api/import/main?' + at +'&' + ak;

   var data = [
      {
        'CustomerID':'9854poiu', 
        'CustomerName':'Fred Blair',
        'SquareFt': 3500,
        'Lead':'Fred Blair'
      }
   ];   

   var options = {  
     'method':'post',
     'contentType': 'application/json', 
     'payload': JSON.stringify(data)
   };  

   var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);  
   var responseCode = response.getResponseCode()
   var responseBody = response.getContentText()

   if (responseCode === 200) {
      var responseJson = JSON.parse(responseBody);
      Logger.log(responseJson);
   } else {
      Logger.log(Utilities.formatString("Request failed. Expected 200, got %d: %s", responseCode, 
      responseBody))
   }
};
```

Result:

```
{
 endpoint=import, 
 params={endpoint=import,
 authenticationToken=<myToken>,
 authenticationKey=<myKey>, 
 dataMain=[],
 action=main}, 
 tokenUsage={requestsReadInLastMinute=2, requestsReadToday=0, requestsWriteToday=105,
 requestsWriteInLastMinute=0}, count=0.0, tokenLimits={limitWriteRequestsPerMinute=60.0,
 limitReadRequestsPerMinute=60.0, limitWriteRequestsPerDay=3000.0, limitReadRequestsPerDay=3000.0}, 
 requestAction=main, processingTime=153 milliseconds, dataIssueDetails=false, success=false
}
```

As you can see, the `dataMain=[]` array should have one object according to the API instructions, but always returns empty?

Is this a problem with my code and am misunderstanding how the API works, or is this an issue with the API? Any help or clues would be very appreciated!

PS. And yes, I have replaced my key and token with `myKey` and `myToken` for security.

Comment: I think that the script of your request is correct. So, for example, when you tested your request with `Try it out`, will you be able to get the values you expect? [Ref](https://pestroutes.api-docs.io/3.1/import/importmainobject)

Comment: @Tanaike, with regards to the 'Try it Out' feature, i don't know how to replace subdomain with my domain in the url: https://subdomain.pestroutes.com/api/import/main, thus it comes back as incorrect authentication. ??

Comment: Thank you for replying. I thought that it might be required to confirm whether the result is changed by the domain at the request side. So I proposed it. But from your replying, I could understand that `Try it out` cannot be used. Thank you for testing it. As other confirmation, for example, when you check `Logger.log(response.getContentText())`, what result will you get?

Comment: @Tanaike, that result comes back as {"params":{"endpoint":"import","action":"main","authenticationToken":"myToken","authenticationKey":"myKey","dataMain":[]},"tokenUsage":{"requestsReadToday":"0","requestsWriteToday":"111","requestsReadInLastMinute":"2","requestsWriteInLastMinute":"0"},"tokenLimits":{"limitReadRequestsPerMinute":60,"limitReadRequestsPerDay":3000,"limitWriteRequestsPerMinute":60,"limitWriteRequestsPerDay":3000},"requestAction":"main","endpoint":"import","success":false,"dataIssueDetails":false,"processingTime":"149 milliseconds","count":0}.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, it was found that when the values is retrieved with `UrlFetchApp`, the length of `dataMain` is `0`. In this case, I thought that the request body might occur this situation. If it's so, how about changing the request body and confirming the response values? But I cannot use this API. So I cannot test it, and also I'm not sure whether this is the correct direction for resolving your issue. This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for this.

Comment: @Tanaike, If what you mean by 'request body' is the var data holding the json object, i have tried dozens of variations, all of which seem to output a good response value as to the var data, but there doesn't seem to be any references to dataMain anywhere in the logs. I may have misunderstood your last post, however this is what i understood your reference to 'response values'  too mean. Thank you very much by the way for helping me troubleshoot this. Also, i have on open support ticket with PestRoutes and will keep the thread posted on any developments.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I could understand about your situation. I deeply apologize that I couldn't resolve your issue soon.

Comment: @Tanaike, thanks again! Just out of curiosity, i just ran this example using google's Golang implementation. It yielded the same results with dataMain[] as empty.

Comment: I took a look at the docs, they claim that you should've got an `dataIssueDetails` field back as part of the response since `success` is `false`, but instead you get `false` - try raising an issue with API support - does not seem right to me. Also, what is the response code (please, update the question)?

Comment: @OlegValter, the response code is 200. Also, i have emailed the API support team and am awaiting a response. Thanks for looking into this.

Comment: @iamtoc - thanks, hope you resolve this! Judging from the employee's answer, there mght be nothing you can do on your side except for switching endpoints...

Answer (score 2):

It looks like this is a question about using the PestRoutes import/main endpoint for import new customers and subscriptions! I am the PestRoutes developer in charge of the API and I would happy to help you <3.

Here is an example for posting a customer to our demo environment:

Abstract:

```
apiModule.call('import','main',{
    "dataMain":[
        {
            "CustomerID": "PestRoutesOverflow1111",
            "Branch": "Demo Pest Control",
            "CustomerName": "PestRoutes Testing01",
            "CustomerAddress": "Walt Disney World Resort, Orlando, FL 32830",
            "CustomerCity": "Orlando",
            "CustomerState": "FL",
            "CustomerZipCode": "32830",
            "CustomerPhone1": "4428675309",
            "CustomerPhone2": "4438675309",
            "CustomerEmail": "",
            "CustomerStatus": "Act"

            //"Frequency": 90,              //These three fields
            //"ServiceType": 'Quarterly',   // are the minimum to
            //"Price": '111',               // create a subscription

            //"Lead": 'No',                 //Set Yes to revert subscription to a LEAD
            //"LastService": '4/26/18',     // If this is set it will override Lead to No
            //"InitialService": '1/26/18',  // If this is set it will override Lead to No
        }
    ]
});
```

here is what that looks like as a curl:

```
curl 'https://demo.pestroutes.com/api/import/main' \
-H 'Connection: keep-alive' \
-H 'Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01' \
-H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.106 Safari/537.36' \
-H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8' \
-H 'Origin: null' \
-H 'Sec-Fetch-Site: cross-site' \
-H 'Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors' \
-H 'Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty' \
-H 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9' \
--data-raw 'dataMain%5B0%5D%5BCustomerID%5D=PestRoutesOverflow1111&dataMain%5B0%5D%5BBranch%5D=Demo+Pest+Control&dataMain%5B0%5D%5BCustomerName%5D=PestRoutes+Testing01&dataMain%5B0%5D%5BCustomerAddress%5D=Walt+Disney+World+Resort%2C+Orlando%2C+FL+32830&dataMain%5B0%5D%5BCustomerCity%5D=Orlando&dataMain%5B0%5D%5BCustomerState%5D=FL&dataMain%5B0%5D%5BCustomerZipCode%5D=32830&dataMain%5B0%5D%5BCustomerPhone1%5D=4428675309&dataMain%5B0%5D%5BCustomerPhone2%5D=4438675309&dataMain%5B0%5D%5BCustomerEmail%5D=&dataMain%5B0%5D%5BCustomerStatus%5D=Act&authenticationKey=88492884d8154febd1057372867c2e34b371d8fb&authenticationToken=6915e71f53708f17dba090febd2df4f9d79364d7' \
--compressed
```

As a fetch:

```
fetch("https://demo.pestroutes.com/api/import/main", {
"headers": {
    "accept": "application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01",
    "accept-language": "en-US,en;q=0.9",
    "content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
    "sec-fetch-dest": "empty",
    "sec-fetch-mode": "cors",
    "sec-fetch-site": "cross-site"
},
"referrerPolicy": "no-referrer-when-downgrade",
"body": "dataMain%5B0%5D%5BCustomerID%5D=PestRoutesOverflow1111&dataMain%5B0%5D%5BBranch%5D=Demo+Pest+Control&dataMain%5B0%5D%5BCustomerName%5D=PestRoutes+Testing01&dataMain%5B0%5D%5BCustomerAddress%5D=Walt+Disney+World+Resort%2C+Orlando%2C+FL+32830&dataMain%5B0%5D%5BCustomerCity%5D=Orlando&dataMain%5B0%5D%5BCustomerState%5D=FL&dataMain%5B0%5D%5BCustomerZipCode%5D=32830&dataMain%5B0%5D%5BCustomerPhone1%5D=4428675309&dataMain%5B0%5D%5BCustomerPhone2%5D=4438675309&dataMain%5B0%5D%5BCustomerEmail%5D=&dataMain%5B0%5D%5BCustomerStatus%5D=Act&authenticationKey=88492884d8154febd1057372867c2e34b371d8fb&authenticationToken=6915e71f53708f17dba090febd2df4f9d79364d7",
"method": "POST",
"mode": "cors",
"credentials": "omit"
}).then( r=>r.json()).then(console.log);
```

First run result:

```
{
    "params": {
        "endpoint": "import",
        "action": "main",
        "dataMain": [],
        "authenticationKey": "88492884d8154febd1057372867c2e34b371d8fb",
        "authenticationToken": "6915e71f53708f17dba090febd2df4f9d79364d7"
    },
    "tokenUsage": {
        "requestsReadToday": "0",
        "requestsWriteToday": "1",
        "requestsReadInLastMinute": "0",
        "requestsWriteInLastMinute": "0"
    },
    "tokenLimits": {
        "limitReadRequestsPerMinute": 1000,
        "limitReadRequestsPerDay": 1000,
        "limitWriteRequestsPerMinute": 1000,
        "limitWriteRequestsPerDay": 1000
    },
    "requestAction": "main",
    "endpoint": "import",
    "success": true,
    "customersImported": [
        {
            "CustomerID": "PestRoutesOverflow1111",
            "PestRoutesCustomerID": "21257",
            "Action": "Created"
        }
    ],
    "processingTime": "1199 milliseconds",
    "count": 0
}
```

Second run result:

```
{
    "params": {
        "endpoint": "import",
        "action": "main",
        "dataMain": [],
        "authenticationKey": "88492884d8154febd1057372867c2e34b371d8fb",
        "authenticationToken": "6915e71f53708f17dba090febd2df4f9d79364d7"
    },
    "tokenUsage": {
        "requestsReadToday": "0",
        "requestsWriteToday": "2",
        "requestsReadInLastMinute": "1",
        "requestsWriteInLastMinute": "0"
    },
    "tokenLimits": {
        "limitReadRequestsPerMinute": 1000,
        "limitReadRequestsPerDay": 1000,
        "limitWriteRequestsPerMinute": 1000,
        "limitWriteRequestsPerDay": 1000
    },
    "requestAction": "main",
    "endpoint": "import",
    "success": true,
    "customersImported": [
        {
            "CustomerID": "PestRoutesOverflow1111",
            "PestRoutesCustomerID": "21257",
            "Action": "Updated"
        }
    ],
    "processingTime": "1036 milliseconds",
    "count": 0
}
```

Note that while the second request with the same CustomerID will update, usage of this endpoint for customer updates is very dangerous and not recommended. (Email me for alternative workflows)

Note that the dataMain object in the result is always empty. For most PestRoutes endpoints this parameter array will return the payload exactly as received, but this is a legacy endpoint and outputs a little strangely; so you can disregard the emptiness of that field as a symptom of error for this particular endpoint.

As for the encoding content-type; application/x-www-form-urlencoded and multipart/form-data are accepted by the server.

Please reach out to me via email at michael ~at~ pestroutes.com for further assistance :)

Comment: Guys, you should really make this info available in the docs... As it stands now, its not at all obvious that the endpoint is legacy and is not recommended. Also, could you please clarify (by updating the answer) what is the source of truth for payload type? In the docs, it is JSON, but in your answer it is urlencoded?

Comment: We appreciate the feedback; the documentation could certainly use some TLC on the finer points of this endpoint and perhaps overall. As for the encoding content-type; application/x-www-form-urlencoded and multipart/form-data are accepted by the server.

Comment: Michael, thank you for getting back and updating the answer to include the information. Just to clarify - is the `application/json` type accepted by the endpoint or only those two? It would also be great to include possible response codes (unless I missed them - but that's a good point to improve their visibility)

Comment: Unfortunately a content type of application/json is not currently accepted by the import/main endpoint at this time.

Comment: Thanks, Michael - it would be even better if you included it in the answer for better visibility, so in case others who encounter the same issue have everything important highlighted

Answer (score 1):

Here was a successful implemntation using UrlFetchApp.fetch adapted from Michael's answer. Thank you all for your support!

```
function runTest() {

  var at = 'authenticationToken=<myToken>';
  var ak = 'authenticationKey=<myKey>';
  var url ='https://simplehome.pestroutes.com/api/import/main?' + at +'&' + ak;

  var data = 'dataMain[0][CustomerID]=548745&dataMain[0][Branch]=Simple Home Maintenance&dataMain[0][CustomerName]=Jill Blair&dataMain[0][CustomerAddress]=248N 600E, St. George, UT 84770&dataMain[0][CustomerCity]=St. George&dataMain[0][CustomerState]=UT&dataMain[0][CustomerZipCode]=84770&dataMain[0][SquareFt]=2500&dataMain[0][CustomerPhone1]=123-456-7890&dataMain[0][CustomerEmail]=fred@blair.com&dataMain[0][CustomerDateAdded]=6/6/2020&dataMain[0][CustomerStatus]=Act&dataMain[0][Notes]=Test Notes&dataMain[0][Lead]=Yes';

  var options = {  
    'headers': {
    'accept': 'application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01',
    'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',      
    'sec-fetch-dest': 'empty',
    'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
    'sec-fetch-site': 'cross-site'
   },
   'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
   'method':'post',
   'payload': data
  };  
    
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);  
  var responseCode = response.getResponseCode();
  var responseBody = response.getContentText();

  Logger.log(responseCode);
  Logger.log(responseBody);

  if (responseCode === 200) {
     var responseJson = JSON.parse(responseBody);
     Logger.log(responseBody);
  } else {
     Logger.log(Utilities.formatString('Request failed. Expected 200, got %d: %s', 
     responseCode, responseBody));
  };

};
```

Result:

```
 {"params":"endpoint":"import","action":"main","authenticationToken":"myToken",
 "authenticationKey":"<myKey>","dataMain":[]},"tokenUsage":"requestsReadToday":"0","requestsWriteToday":"25","requestsReadInLastMinute":"1","requestsWriteInLastMinute":"0"},"tokenLimits":{"limitReadRequestsPerMinute":60,"limitReadRequestsPerDay":3000,"limitWriteRequestsPerMinute":60,"limitWriteRequestsPerDay":3000},"requestAction":"main","endpoint":"import","success":true,"customersImported":[{"CustomerID":"548745","PestRoutesCustomerID":"10109","Action":"Updated"}],"processingTime":"587 milliseconds","count":0}
```